# How to echo the correct number of rows of a table

Tags: php, mysql

Need the number of rows of a table.

```
$st = $db->query("select count(*) from images");
$total = $st->rowCount();
echo $total;
```

result - `1`

The table `images` has `2430` rows.

How to get the correct number of rows?

Comment: you are using PDO ??

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt` and then `echo $st['cnt']`

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă, your code results in a `fatal error`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using PDO  you could use

```
$result = $con->prepare("select count(*) from images"); 
$result->execute(); 
$total = $result->fetchColumn(); 
echo $total;
```

assuming $con is your connection  to db

from PHP doc

> DOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the
>   last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding
>   PDOStatement object.
>
> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
>   a SELECT statement, **some databases may return the number of rows
>   returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed
>   for all databases** and should not be relied on for portable
>   applications.

Comment: and what is then the purpose of `rowCount()` function?

Comment: for sure   rowCount() function? return the number of rows  affected  by  DELETE INSERT OR UPDATE https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php  ..but not (sure) for SELECT

Answer (score -3):

Using PHP and MYSQLi functions

```
$query = "select * from images";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

This will output the total number of rows in the table

Of Course this presupposes that a connection has already been established to the database using $db

Comment: `rowCount()` is PDO, not `mysqli_*`.

Comment: This is a relatively bad answer if you have a large table with lots of columns, it's ineffective to select everything when unnecessary.

Comment: @SamyokNepal, is then `select count(*)` also a bed solution - the same reason?

Comment: @qadenza As I understand it, that's trivially ineffective as it is run on the SQL server instead of the PHP server (all the columns are never sent to PHP) -- for your case, it's fine.

Comment: @SamyokNepal perhaps. Another simple hack I do is to just run select for a single column possibly the "_id" column and test how many records are returned